Need help saving pyspark dataframe to iceberg that has a void column
Problem: I need to save a dataframe into Iceberg, but it refuses to do so until i drop a void column. I also need to as close as possible preserve the existing structure of other columns, so any flattening or other transformation would need reversed.
I'm trying to either drop the column, or convince Iceberg to allow me to write the DF regardless. I don't know of anyway to do the latter, and while the former should be easy, the nesting makes it difficult.
The problem with dropping the column comes from it being so deeply nested that I can't figure out the write syntax for doing so.
I'll explain the problem as well as what I've tried that hasn't worked.
Without deleting ALL of A or ALL of B directly, how do I delete the array C in a DataFrame whose df.printSchema() looks something like this:
root
 |-- foobar: string (nullable = true)
 |-- A: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- B: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- foo: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- bar: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- C: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: void (containsNull = true)

(note there are actually thousands of columns, limited output to the relevant part.)
Context:
I'm doing data engineering work, and I've got a very large and very nested DataFrame, and I'm trying to persist the DataFrame into Iceberg. This phase of the work I'm trying to keep the data as close to "raw" as possible, where I'm tasked limiting modifications of the data to only strict type changes, and PII masking. this is so this storage could be used as an archive, and potential backup recovery. Iceberg
I am open to ideas that involve expanding the nested arrays out, provided there is a repeatable and sure way to pack the array back into the original structure.
What I've tried that do NOT work.
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, transform

df = df.drop('A.B.C') # if only it was THIS simple....

df = df.drop('A.[].B.[].C') # I know, but I had to try
df = df.drop('A[].B[].C') # I know, but I had to try
df = df.drop('A.[]B.[]C') # I know, but I had to try

# what most examples online suggest
df = df.withColumn('A.B', transform(col('A.B'), lambda x: x.dropFields('C')))
df = df.withColumn('A', transform(col('A'), lambda x: x.dropFields('B.C')))

# 
df = df.withColumn(
    "A",
    transform(
        col("A"),
        lambda x: x.withColumn(
            "B",
            transform(
                col("B"),
                lambda y: y.dropFields("C")
            )
        )

Some of these no-op'd and just silently failed to find a column and then did nothing.
The latter ones threw parsing errors.
